# Integrate Kupfer functionality in Dash

Tags: unity, unity-dash

Is there a way to integrate some of [Kupfer's](http://engla.github.io/kupfer/) functionality in the Dash search? I like Dash, but it's lacking some nice features: (I know I'm being a bit fussy.)

- Partial search - In Kupfer I don't have to type exactly in order. Let's say, I have both version 3.7 and 4.3 of Eclipse installed. In Kupfer I can search for the former by typing in `Ec3`. No need to type out `Eclipse 3`.
- Calculator - e.g. Typing `=2 + sqrt(2) * pi` gives me the result
- There's a plugin to use the browsers search engines. So I can highlight something in a text document and then open Kupfer and type in `Du`, which is enough to find `DuckDuckGo` and then search for the hightlighted text on that site. Of course I can also first select the search engine and then type my text to search for.
- I can search for an application and then set it up to start in 3 minutes with just a few keystrokes. (The same can be done for showing a message on screen. For example, to remind me of something.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the answer is no, not without so much work that it would outweigh the minor inconvenience of using Kupfer directly for the things it does well.

As your examples do a great job of highlighting, it's a very useful app.

Unity Dash is also useful, but its UI seems entirely oriented toward search, one-field search. (Modulo configurable filtering.) It's hard to imagine how you would bring into Dash the kind of subject-verb command composition that's part of what makes Kupfer so handy -- without essentially cloning Kupfer. And since you already have Kupfer, you don't need a clone.

I don't mean to dismiss your question, but nonetheless I can't see a way to answer "yes" to it. If you're still determined, and have one specific favorite feature of Kupfer you'd most like Dash to emulate, you might try asking about that.